# ConTeXt: Fontawesome symbols with MetaFun

Tags: context, fontawesome, metafun

I am trying unsuccessfully to pass fontawesome symbols as variable to MetaFun.

I tried things like, passing the symbol directly through the variable

```
\usesymbols [fontawesome]


\startuniqueMPgraphic{MPfa}{symbol}
  picture pic ;
  pic := textext.rt(\MPvar{symbol}) ;

  draw pic ;
\stopuniqueMPgraphic


\starttext
  \useMPgraphic{MPfa}{symbol=\symbol[fontawesome-solid][font-awesome]}
\stoptext
```

Passing only the fontawesome flag

```
\usesymbols [fontawesome]


\startuniqueMPgraphic{MPfa}{symbol}
  picture pic ;
  pic := textext.rt(\symbol[fontawesome-solid][\MPvar{symbol}]) ;

  draw pic ;
\stopuniqueMPgraphic


\starttext
  \useMPgraphic{MPfa}{symbol=font-awesome}
\stoptext
```

Using `MPtext` and `MPString` both with `MPvar`

```
\usesymbols [fontawesome]


\setMPtext{fa}{\symbol[fontawesome-solid][font-awesome]}


\startuniqueMPgraphic{MPfa}{symbol}
  picture pic ;
  pic := textext.rt(\MPString{\MPvar{symbol}}) ;

  draw pic ;
\stopuniqueMPgraphic


\starttext
  \useMPgraphic{MPfa}{symbol=fa}
\stoptext
```

and without `MPvar`

```
\usesymbols [fontawesome]


\setMPtext{fa}{\symbol[fontawesome-solid][font-awesome]}


\startuniqueMPgraphic{MPfa}{symbol}
  picture pic ;
  pic := textext.rt(\MPString{symbol}) ;

  draw pic ;
\stopuniqueMPgraphic


\starttext
  \useMPgraphic{MPfa}{symbol=fa}
\stoptext
```

However nothing seems to compile. What did I miss ?

Comment: What do you want, exactly. If you consider a workaround, you can try the following: `\usesymbols [fontawesome]
\startuseMPgraphic{MPfa}
picture p; p := thelabel.rt("\MPtext{fasymbol}", origin);
draw p;
\stopuseMPgraphic
\def\fampsym#1{\setMPtext{fasymbol}{\symbol[fontawesome][#1]}\useMPgraphic{MPfa}}
\starttext
\fampsym{check} \fampsym{globe}
\stoptext`

Comment: In p. 143 of Metafun manual some commands for TeX content are provided: http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/metafun-p.pdf

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you intend to use this. Depending on that, there may be simpler solutions.

Comment: Well, I came to a better solution by cutting down what I wanted in simpler pieces. Ultimately I used overlays. There probably is a much better solution but at my level of ConTeXt-fu I can't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is a late answer, but the following trick may be helpful to other ConTeXt users: prefixing `s::` to your variable name and using `\MPvariable` instead of `\MPvar` let you pass strings:

```
\usesymbols[fontawesome]

\startuniqueMPgraphic{MPfa}{s::symbol}
  picture pic ;
  pic := textext.rt("\symbol[fontawesome][\MPvariable{symbol}]") ;
  draw pic;% scaled 10; %for dramatic effects
\stopuniqueMPgraphic

\startTEXpage
\useMPgraphic{MPfa}{symbol=bell}
\stopTEXpage
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

None of your examples work because ConTeXt allows only a few certain argument types for the `\useMPgraphic` etc. commands.

Only the following three argument type for a key are possible:

1. The name of a color,
2. a number or
3. a valid dimension.

In your example you never pass a valid argument to the `symbol` key which result in the error message.

Comment: So there is no better way than in @JairoADelRio answer ?

Comment: There are different methods to implement it (e.g. using `\setvariables` to pass the values) it's the way you should go.